# Show month as a row postgresql

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have this table, i call it transaction table

```
id  periode_month   total_amount
U1       1           1000
U1       2           1200
U1       3           1000
U1       4           1000
U2       2           1250
```

I'm trying to achieve this

```
id  month 1 month 2 month 3 month 4 month 5 ... month 12
U1  1000    1200    1000    1000      0           0
U2   0      1250      0       0       0           0
```

Here is what i do so far

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'select client_id, periode_month, total_amount
   from sucor_transactions
   order by 1,2')
AS ct(userid VARCHAR, periode_month int, total_amount numeric);
```

my query above returning this error `return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible`

then, i'm using google again and i found different query

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab (
 $$SELECT client_id, periode_month,"total_amount"
   FROM   sucor_transactions
   ORDER  BY 1,2$$
   ) AS t (
        class int
        -- "value" double precision  -- column does not exist in result!
    );
```

but it is returning this error `return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible`. How can i solve my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.. Paste yor table data as formatted text here instead.

Comment: hi @Sund'er, thank you. I already remove the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In crosstab, you need to user order by , and give the year column in double quotes

For filtering the month i used generate series.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB (
'SELECT id,periode_month,total_amount
FROM crospost order by 1,2' ,'SELECT g FROM generate_series(1,12) g') 
  AS ct(id varchar , "month 1" int, "month 2" int, "month 3" int, 
  "month 4" int, "month 5" int, "month 6" int,
  "month 7" int, "month 8" int, "month 9" int,
  "month 10" int, "month 11" int, "month 12" int);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer it is working as i expected